# Cgminer not working on windows with Nvidia graphics card

Tags: cgminer

When I try to start cgminer on windows it throws the following error:

```
Command:
cgminer –-scrypt -o http://netcodepool.org:8337 -u usernmae -p mypass –-thread-concurrency 8192 -I 10 -g 1 -w 256


:687: error: no matching overload found for arguments of type 'unsigned int  __attribute__((ext_vector_type(
        4))), unsigned int'
                        B[i+4] = EndianSwap(tmp[i]);
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~
        :700: error: no matching overload found for arguments of type 'unsigned in [2013-05-25 07:10:52] Failed to i
        nit GPU thread 0, disabling device 0
         [2013-05-25 07:10:52] Restarting the GPU from the menu will not fix this.
         [2013-05-25 07:10:52] Try restarting cgminer.
        Press enter to continue:
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the command you started cgminer with?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Take all the extra parameters out of your command line and let cgminer use the default settings: `cgminer –-scrypt -o http://netcodepool.org:8337 -u usernmae -p mypass`

Answer (score 1):

If you using a Nvidia card you should use cudaMiner since you will get better hash rates for it. https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=167229.0

Answer (score 0):

What kind of graphics card do you have? Check out the bitcointalk forum post about this (https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=171515.0)

Basically, ["The auto gpu and fan settings are only for ATI cards I believe."](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=171515.msg1971560#msg1971560) If you have a different one, perhaps change your settings.